Can Spanish language GBA Pokémon connect to English Gamecube Pokémon games?
Can Spanish language GBA Pokémon connect to English Gamecube Pokémon games?
If I have a legit Pokémon cartridge with Spanish language (RojoFuego Rubí for example) can I still trade Pokémon between these (with Game Boy Player) and Pokémon Colosseum and XD on Gamecube, being US English versions?
Thanks in advance.
